# Is there a way to remove white margins when importing a pdf file?

Tags: pdfcrop

A workaround is to use `pdfcrop` separately (in the terminal) to crop the PDF file we want to import.

However - is there a way to remove white margins when importing a PDF file from within the `tex` file?

The two common packages to import PDF files are `pdfpages` or `graphicx`. Can I 'preprocess' a file for them with `pdfcrop` within `tex` file?

Comment: What do you mean by importing?  Do you mean embedding a page or series of pages from a PDF in a Tex document?

Comment: I have a lot of plots saved separately as PDF files and now I would like to embed/import (I'm not sure what's the right phrase) them one by one into a Tex document.

Comment: With shell-escape enabled you _might_ be able to call `pdfcrop` from your TeX document. I don't know whether the cropping would be synchronous (good) or asynchronous (bad).

Comment: Can't you just run `pdfcrop` on all the files first, e.g. with a for loop? Which operating system do you use?

Comment: I use Ubuntu. Well, in principle I could run a loop first but I wanted to be able to crop the files on-the-go.
Following Ethan's advice and enabling shell I can now use:
`\immediate\write18{pdfcrop charge_distribution.pdf tmp.pdf}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{tmp.pdf}`
Now I would like to try to create some kind of macro (or some similar structure, I am not that familiar with LaTeX yet) that would enable me to do that in a quicker way

Comment: (`for f in *.pdf do ; pdfcrop $f ; done` is quite quick, isn't it?) Sure, it's a perfectly reasonable request. You may want some way of turning off the cropping, or checking for a cropped file,  otherwise the cropping will be done every time you compile your document. That is partly the reason I would do it outside  the LaTeX file, it's something you need to do just once.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A new command that works like `\includegraphics`, but crops the pdf image:

```
\newcommand{\includeCroppedPdf}[2][]{%
    \immediate\write18{pdfcrop #2}%
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2-crop}}
```

**Remember:** `\write18` needs to be enabled. For most TeX distros set the `--shell-escape` flag when running `latex`/`pdflatex` etc.

## Example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\includeCroppedPdf}[2][]{%
    \immediate\write18{pdfcrop #2}%
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2-crop}}

\begin{document}
    \includeCroppedPdf[width=\textwidth]{test}
\end{document}
```

## Avoid cropping on every compile

To avoid cropping on every document compilation, you could check if the cropped file already exists. (some checksum would be better)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\includeCroppedPdf}[2][]{%
    \IfFileExists{./#2-crop.pdf}{}{%
        \immediate\write18{pdfcrop #2 #2-crop.pdf}}%
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2-crop.pdf}}

\begin{document}
    \includeCroppedPdf[width=\textwidth]{test}
\end{document}
```

## MD5 Checksum Example

The Idea is to save the MD5 of the image and compare it on the next run. This requires the `\pdf@filemdfivesum` macro (only works with `PDFLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`). For `XeLaTeX` You could use `\write18` with `md5sum` utility or do a file diff.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\includeCroppedPdf}[2][]{\begingroup%
    \edef\temp@mdfivesum{\pdf@filemdfivesum{#2.pdf}}%
    \ifcsstrequal{#2mdfivesum}{temp@mdfivesum}{}{%
        %file changed
        \immediate\write18{pdfcrop #2 #2-crop.pdf}}%
        \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\expandafter\string\gdef\string\csname\space #2mdfivesum\string\endcsname{\temp@mdfivesum}}%
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2-crop.pdf}\endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \includeCroppedPdf[width=\textwidth]{abc}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I've been working on, thank you

Comment: @tales You're welcome! Just added a MD5 example that also might be useful.

Comment: Doesn't the pdfcrop package already do something like this? Actually, that just seems to give you the command which you use here, and the rpdfcrop command, I guess.

Comment: I believe what @caenrigen says in his answer ("Does not work when the `\graphicspath` is changed") applies to the checksum part of this answer, too. For me, `#2mdfivesum` macros are empty.

Answer (score -1):

If anyone runs into issue due to spaces in the filename path, the following solves the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\includeCroppedPdf}[2][]{\begingroup%
    \edef\temp@mdfivesum{\pdf@filemdfivesum{"#2.pdf"}}%
    \ifcsstrequal{#2mdfivesum}{temp@mdfivesum}{}{%
        %file changed
        \immediate\write18{pdfcrop "#2.pdf" "#2-crop.pdf"}}%
        \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\expandafter\string\gdef\string\csname\space #2mdfivesum\string\endcsname{\temp@mdfivesum}}%
    \includegraphics[#1]{"#2-crop"}\endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \includeCroppedPdf[width=\textwidth]{./path to file with spaces/abc efg}
\end{document}
```

NB: Does not work when the `\graphicspath` is changed