# \begingroup, \endgroup expansion problem "Undefined control sequence."

Tags: errors, expansion

I just created an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151646/is-there-a-way-to-remove-white-margins-when-importing-a-pdf-file/151669#151669) that uses a temporary variable with `\write\@auxout` and thought it would be good idea to scope with `\begingroup`, `\endgroup`. For some Reason this results in:

> ! Undefined control sequence. 
> <write> \tempvariable

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\abc}{%
    \begingroup%
    \newcommand\tempvariable{\relax}%
    \write\@auxout{\tempvariable}%
    \endgroup%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    Why isn't this working???
    \abc 

\end{document}
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `\immediate` should help:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\abc}{%
   \begingroup%
    \newcommand\tempvariable{\relax}%
%    \write\@auxout{\tempvariable}%
\immediate \write\@auxout{\tempvariable}%
    \endgroup%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    Why isn't this working???
    \abc 

\end{document}
```

I can see from your anwer from the link, that you know command `\immediate`, so probably no additional comment is needed.

Comment: Thx you, I must be blind ;). Anyone else with this problem might want to read this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115932/on-the-basics-of-writing-to-reading-from-auxiliary-files-aux-toc-etc