# How to crop background from image automatically?

Tags: graphics, packages, crop

I have a Google Docs drawing that is a small scheme. However, this small scheme is surrounded by a lot of background that occupies a lot of useless space.

[image]

I do not want to remove the background manually because I may need the extra space in the future.

I know Latex has a lot of image packages, so I was wondering if there is some package that I can use to automatically detect that useless background and crop my image so I do not have all that white space around it.

I know some of you will suggest the external tool pdfcrop. I have experimented with it, but it does not crop the image at all.

[Here is the png](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/185FtxRZ5MSFkcYwwyZL2fQnDpTdHJFrrugrnz8TalRs/pub?w=960&h=540) image file and [here is the pdf](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/785815/middleware_first_view.pdf) version downloaded with Gdocs.

Comment: You can try `pdfcrop` if it is a pdf. Gimp or imagemagick or ghostscript if it is an image.

Comment: Can you give me a MWE with an image in PDF format (using pdfcrop)? I am quite new at this :S

Comment: For which one?. In gimp simply open it and try to chop off. For `pdfcrop` it is `pdfcrop file.pdf filecropped.pdf` and for imagemagick `convert  -trim file.png file-trimmed.png` from command prompt.

Comment: Ahh, so Latex has no packages that can do this automatically for me? I have to do it manually using an external tool?

Comment: See the answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151646/3954 for a way to use `pdfcrop` from within you document.

Comment: Well, graphicx can do this but you have to decide from where to clip. On the other hand you can write a batch file or bash script. If you are interested in batch file let me know.

Comment: @HarishKumar: How would this batch script work? Could I then use it with latex so I dont have to run it manually every time I add a new image?

Comment: pdfcrop tool does not seem to work at all :S I have added the png image and the pdf file for future refrence.

Comment: pdfcrop needs perl. The answer linked by Gonzalo may be a best shot for you.

Comment: @HarishKumar: The reason I found out that pdfcrop does not work at all its because I experimented the solutions provided in the link he gave me :P

Comment: You have to compile that example with `--shell-escape`

Comment: I don't understand the point about needing the space in the future at all. Why don't you just make a copy of the image?

Comment: @cfr: if I wanted to manually create a copy, or manually trim the images myself, I would not be asking this question here :S I am looking for an automatic way to do it.

Comment: @HarishKumar: how do I compile an example in Latex with `--shell-escape` in Kile?

Comment: OK So the issue is not really to avoid making a copy. It is to avoid making one *manually*? I guess since you are looking at `pdfcrop` or `convert`, the copy part is OK.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098965/using-imagemagick-how-do-i-crop-out-the-white-background || http://askubuntu.com/questions/97695/is-there-a-lightweight-tool-to-crop-images-quickly

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You do not need a cropped copy with a external program, only add some options to `\includegraphics`. This MWE show the same image twice (renamed to `image.png`) , with and without the useless background. Both images are  inside a framed box to show the edges:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\section*{Original image} 

\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image.png}}

\section*{Trimmed and clipped image} 

\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,trim=6.5cm 6cm 6.5cm 4cm,clip]{image.png}}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**: Since the goal seem to be the automatic cropping more that avoid a cropped copy, but as far I know this has been perfectly solved in the comments with an external tool, this is only to  put in practice to in a MWE. The following code with a poorman's macro added to the above MWE:

```
\section*{Automatic crop}
Note: compile with \verb|--shell-escape|\\

\newcommand\cropped[1]{%
    \immediate\write18{convert -trim #1.png #1cropped.png}%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#1cropped.png}}

\fbox{\cropped{image}}
```

Will produce this image automatically:

[image: MWE]

Really the cropping was not make really by LaTeX and need one extra file, but who cares? Anyway is done while running `pdflatex`.

Comment: Yes but, can this trim be done automatically by an algorithm?

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix Do you mean like the `Autocrop` or  `Zealous Crop` commands in Gimp? This mean  pattern recognition and image recognition, that is, analyze the bitmaps and vector images. I am afraid that this is asking too much for a *text* typographic system.  But who know, I am still learning ... `:)`

Comment: yes exactly like autocrop in gimp. I heard that this is in fact possible, and that one can use pdfcrop to achieve that, but I am not sure how to do it :S

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix I added an example using convert and the png image. I cannot test now, pdfcrop, but should be nearly the same, although may be cropping only the text margins, not  the blank areas of a included bitmap. But you convert to PNG and -trim at the same time.  (`convert -trim image.pdf image.png`).

Comment: Alright ... how do I run this with `--shell-escape` using Kile? xD

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix This is only a option of pdflatex: `pdflatex --shell-escape file.tex` compile the above MWE  executing also `convert`. In Kile you can pass this option to the compiler in  `Setting` > `Configure Kile` > `Tools` > `Build` > `PDFLaTeX` > `General`.

Comment: The dimensions: \includegraphics[trim=left bottom right top, clip]