# How to automatically eliminate white space around a figure?

Tags: graphics, floats

I am creating figures in Powerpoint to be included as PDF files in my LaTeX document. I know one can use a combination of trim and clip to eliminate the white space around a figure. But this requires the specification of the amount of white space around the figure (measurements for trim). Is there a way to just crop the image automatically so that it is only as large as the bounding box for the contents

Comment: Not at compile time, but you can try with [`pdfcrop`](//ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop).

Comment: Also related: [How to crop background from image automatically?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165961/how-to-crop-background-from-image-automatically)

Comment: If we can get this question re-opened, I'll tell you about a Powerpoint macro I wrote that allows me to save automatically-cropped pdf files with a single click. Before I wrote this, I did cropping manually using either PDFCropper or Briss.