# I am unable to add the text after the PDF table inserted in latex

Tags: includegraphics

```latex
\begin{table}
\centering
    \caption{TEST}
    \vspace{-25mm}
    \makebox[0pt]{%
    \includegraphics[width=18cm,height=27cm,scale=2.5]{Table1.pdf}}
\label{table1}
\end{table}
```

I am able to insert the pdf in the latex page floating environment. The table has only 3 rows and 3 columns. It fit 1/4 of the page accurately according to the A4 size. But remaining page it shows empty.If, I add another pdf table same issue happening. I want to write the text in remaining of the page .Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Open the pdf with an external pdf viewer. Are there large white margins?

Comment: Your image is extremely large. Try the following: `\begin{figure}
\centering
    \caption{TEST}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Table1.pdf}
\label{table1}
\end{figure}`. Consider @Fran answer!!!

Answer (score 4):

Too long for a comment:

Whithout a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem is imposible find real the problems-s and possible solutions. As is, the question is a guess game, since we cannot see the PDF image, nor the  document class, preamble and context that possibly are causing/influencing the output, that is also hidden.

Unless you edit the question to produce compilable code starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`, the only evident for me is that:

1. The `scale` option have not sense, and it is not used, if you use `width` or `height` options.
2. Accordingly, your image is set to fill the whole page (assuming that you are using A4) and maybe exceeding margins.
3. Do not set both `width` and `height` unless (a) do you want a flattened or stretched image with exactly this dimensions or (b) do you use also `keepsaspectratio` to scale porportionally as far as possible without exceed these dimensions. Usually is enough fix only the width (or alternatively only the height) since the image always will be scaled proportionally).
4. The zero box is useless if you want the imagen between margins.
5. If the pdf image have white margins, you should now about the `trim`and `clip` options. See [How to crop background from image automatically?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165961/how-to-crop-background-from-image-automatically).
6. For the love of God, for a simple 3x3 table, write it in LaTeX, using a tabular environment o similar.