# \settoheight is slightly shorter than actual height

Tags: lengths

I am trying to set a length to the height of a heading. I have the following snippet.

```
% heading height
\settoheight{\headingh}{\Huge{\textbf{\heading}}}

\centering\Huge\textbf{\heading}\rule{0.1mm}{\headingh}
```

The result of which is the following.

[image: Heading Height]

As you can see, the letter is slightly taller than the rule. If I run \settoheight on the rule, the resulting length is the same as the \headingh length.

Here is a minimum reproducible example.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newlength{\headingh}

\begin{document}
\settoheight{\headingh}{\Huge\textbf{A}}
\Huge\textbf{A}\rule{0.1mm}{\headingh}
\end{document}
```

I have used the same font as in the original, but the same effect is present even when the default font is used, i.e. with lines 2-4 commented out.

Comment: This is why: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275374/what-is-the-local-height-of-a-capital-letter/275381#275381 See "overshoot" https://ilovetypography.com/2009/01/14/inconspicuous-vertical-metrics/

Comment: You might want to use \ht\strutbox instead.  It is faster and at least should be big enough.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes That begs the question, is there a way to measure the actual height automatically with a latex script?

Comment: Apparently, not directly in LaTeX.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165961/how-to-crop-background-from-image-automatically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the choice of the font designer, the height depth and width of each character is *specified* in the font metrics, they are not measured from the visible shape of the character. pdftex has no information about which pixels are black and which white, each character is just a rectangle.