# Crop pdf graph to remove margins

Tags: pdf, crop

I have input a graph as pdf into my latex document but there is a big white space underneath it. How do I crop my pdf so that is only includes the graph and no margins???

Comment: If it is truly a (big) *white* space, consider using [`pdfcrop`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop) to remove it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is there a way to remove white margins when importing a PDF file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151646/5764)